# Clearing the default value of an input element in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input element with a default value set and I'm trying to clear it, this is how it looks like:

```
<input id="something" type="text" value="test" />
```

I'm trying following:

```
$("#something").val("");
```

Which seems to be working in Chrome, but not in IE9/IE10. Any ideas, or a workaround ?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TBB4N/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

```
$("#something").attr('value','');
```

OR (Above JQuery 1.8)

```
$("#something").prop('value','');
```

Comment: I have tested your fiddle in IE, not working. error message as shown by @Tushar Gupta

Comment: oh i tested in linux machine if not working means try with 2.0.3

Comment: Well, `.attr("value", "")` is working for me on all the browsers.

Comment: ok the answer helps means accept as answer or any help comment it

Answer (score 1):

Error on console in IE

```
jquery-2.0.2.js, line 1378 character 2
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
_display, line 20 character 1
```

[image]

---

Changed jQuery version 2.x edge

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/D7EkL/)

Comment: OP is not worried about older version of jQUery `but not in IE9/IE10`

Comment: Yep, so it is a version issue, I though 2+ is ok with IE9+. Very very lame.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov yeah :) jQuery 2.0.2 issue .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jQuery 2.0.2 has some issues with IE, use 2.0.3

If you enable debug mode in IE developer tools > script, you can see the following error

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied. jquery-2.0.2.js, line 1378 character 2

```
$(function(){
    $("#clear1").on("click", function() {
        $("#something").val("");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xxMF/6/)

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3 in my project, there is no error in the console but doesn't work. Not sure how to re-create it in a fiddle.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov did you enable the debugger and check what is happening

Comment: Yep, placed break points, and all. The value just stays the same. I did try `$("#something").attr("value", "");` which seems to be working, but it feels a bit ... dirty :), not sure if it's a good approach.

Comment: I've got my current jquery version from NuGet (which is 2.0.3), in jsfiddle when I select 2.x edge (not sure what that means), it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very new version of jQuery that isn't designed for older IE's. You should use jQuery  1.10.2

can implement it from here:
     //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondered why it is not working in IEs.  If jQuery fails, try it in JS

```
document.getElementById('something').value= "";
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBB4N/5/)